How to delete the plugins folder ? it's part of a package i downloaded and imported and then deleted the package but can't delete the plugins
after imported the package i didn't see in the package manager any uninstall button only import and re-download.
so i deleted everything in the package in the assets but can't delete the plugins folder.
got message with some loaded dll but i looked in the task manager and didn't find anything related to the Chunity package.
i tried to save and closed the project and re opened but still can't delete it.


Can you delete it from File Explorer while Unity is closed? If not, you can figure out what's locking the file with Resource Monitor, stop the application, then delete it manually.
